# Iterate 'google_cloudfunctions_function' with trigger_http and event_trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to migrate from one GCP environment to another.

There's a JSON holding all the relevant keys.
This allows iteration from JSON to Terraform, resulting in a simplified resource creation.

I've encountered an error with keys that conflict each other - `https_trigger` `event_trigger`. Both need to be configured in the code but if one is set the other cannot be used.

I've tried various things but there is one small problem with the `event_trigger` block, it is optional but once stated the keys inside must contain a value. **I've tried setting those values to 'null' but Terraform is now treating it as a defined value, but with a null value, which is still invalid.**

Here's a sample JSON

```
{
  "AuthenticatedFunction": {
    "entryPoint": "helloWorld",
    "timeout": "60",
    "available_memory_mb": 256,
    "environmentVariables": {
      "RUN": "VALUE",
      "RUNAGAIN": "VALUEAGAIN"
    },
    "buildEnvironmentVariables": {
      "BUILDATMAX": "50",
      "BUILDATMIN": "1"
    },
    "secrets": {
      "secretEnvironmentVariables": [
        {
          "key": "RandomVariable",
          "projectId": "1001384248257",
          "secret": "password",
          "version": "1"
        }
      ],
      "secretVolumes": [
        {
          "mountPath": "/secret",
          "projectId": "1001384248257",
          "secret": "mysecret",
          "versions": [
            {
              "version": "latest",
              "path": "/mysecret"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "httpsTrigger": {
      "url": "https://us-central1-cc-s2s-vpn-test.cloudfunctions.net/function-1"
    }
  },
  "AllocatedFunction": {
    "entryPoint": "helloPubSub",
    "timeout": "60",
    "available_memory_mb": 256,
    "environmentVariables": null,
    "buildEnvironmentVariables": null,
    "secrets": {},
    "eventTrigger": {
      "resource": "projects/cc-s2s-vpn-test/topics/elazar-asdasdx",
      "eventType": "google.pubsub.topic.publish",
      "failurePolicy": {
        "retry": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my terraform snippet

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "secret_test_func" {
  for_each = local.functions

  name        = each.key
  description = "Test - ${each.key}"
  runtime     = "nodejs16"
  region      = var.gcp_functions_region
  entry_point = "catalog_sync" # Entrypoint should be a function in the code

  vpc_connector = google_vpc_access_connector.serverless_vpc.id
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.function_bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name

  available_memory_mb   = each.value.available_memory_mb
  timeout               = each.value.timeout
  trigger_http = lookup(each.value, "httpTrigger", null) == null ? null : true
  
  event_trigger {
    event_type = lookup(each.value, "httpsTrigger", null) == null ? lookup(each.value, "eventTrigger", {}).eventType : null
    resource   = lookup(each.value, "httpsTrigger", null) == null ? lookup(each.value, "eventTrigger", {}).resource : null
  }

  # Environment Variables
  environment_variables = lookup(each.value, "environment_variables", null) != null ? {
    for key, value in each.value.environmentVariables :
    key => value
  } : null

  # Build Environment Variables
  build_environment_variables = lookup(each.value, "build_environment_variables", null) != null ?{
    for key, value in each.value.buildEnvironmentVariables :
    key => value
  } : null

  # Secrets Exposed as an environment variable
  dynamic "secret_environment_variables" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value.secrets, "secretEnvironmentVariables", [])
    content {
      key = secret_environment_variables.value.key
      project_id = secret_environment_variables.value.projectId
      secret = secret_environment_variables.value.secret
      version = secret_environment_variables.value.secret
    }
  }

  # Secrets Mounted as a volume
  dynamic "secret_volumes" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value.secrets, "secretVolumes", [])
    content {
      mount_path = secret_volumes.value.mountPath
      secret     = secret_volumes.value.secret
      project_id = secret_volumes.value.projectId

      dynamic "versions" {
        for_each = secret_volumes.value.versions
        content {
          path    = versions.value.path
          version = versions.value.version
        }
      }
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      source_archive_bucket,source_archive_object,labels["deployment-tool"]
    ]
  }
}
```

**When setting it to null the error I received was**

`│ The argument "event_trigger.0.event_type" is required, but no definition was found.`

**When setting it to false the error I received was**

```
│ Error: googleapi: Error 400: The request has errors
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
│     "fieldViolations": [
│       {
│         "description": "Unknown event_type false",
│         "field": "event_trigger"
│       }
│     ]
│   }
│ ]
│ , badRequest
│
│   with google_cloudfunctions_function.secret_test_func["AuthenticatedFunction"],
│   on functions.tf line 12, in resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "secret_test_func":
│   12: resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "secret_test_func" {
```

One of the two cloud functions did pass when setting it to false.

[Terraform resource documenation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_function)

[You may be able to replicate here](https://github.com/awakzdev/cloud-functions-fetch/blob/main/terraform.tf)

Comment: What are your GCP and TF provider versions? Maybe need to upgrade to the newest.

Comment: GCP - `hashicorp/google = 4.49.0` TF `required version = ">= 0.14"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `event_trigger` block is **not** optional in your code. It is always executed, and that's why it fails. To proper way to make a block optional is through [dynamic blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks):

```
  dynamic "event_trigger" {
  
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "eventTrigger", null) == null ? [0]: [1] 
  
    content {
        event_type = try(each.value.eventTrigger.eventType, null)
        resource = try(each.value.eventTrigger.resource, null)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I did try creating a dynamic block just without a coditional check to it and it failed. this does seem to partially work which is by itself progress. An error occurs if one of the function is of type `httpsTrigger` - `each.value is object with 7 attributes (This object does not have an attribute named "eventTrigger".)`

Comment: @Elazar I updated the answer, but if its still does not work, you have to update the question (or make new question) with current code version and new FULL error msg. Its not clear from your comment what you are doing that could cause the error.

Comment: There was a slight modification to your command but it eventually worked. It seems like you did understand :) 

`for_each = contains(keys(each.value), "eventTrigger") ? [1] : []`
`event_type = each.value.eventTrigger.eventType`
`resource   = each.value.eventTrigger.resource`